# Trying to move an Expression Engine site to Wordpress, but not having luck with content

Tags: migration

I have an Expression Engine site that I'm trying to export to a WordPress site using this guide https://kingdesignllc.com/blog/migrating-from-expression-engine-to-wordpress/. It's working ok, except I can't get all of the content to import into WordPress.

This brings in a couple of paragraphs - content:encoded></content:encoded> - but the rest of the content can't be imported because it's within this tag:
<wp:meta_key>extended</wp:meta_key>
<wp:meta_value></wp:meta_value>
excerpt:encoded</excerpt:encoded>

Anyone have an idea on how to combine the two so I can import all of the content? The entire template is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>

<link>{site_url}</link>
<description>My Site</description>
<pubDate>{current_time format="{DATE_RSS}"}</pubDate>
<generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=2.8.6</generator>
<language>en</language>
<wp:wxr_version>1.0</wp:wxr_version>
<wp:base_site_url>{homepage}</wp:base_site_url>
<wp:base_blog_url>{site_url}</wp:base_blog_url>
{exp:weblog:categories style="linear" weblog="default_site"}
<wp:category>
<wp:category_nicename>{category_url_title}</wp:category_nicename>
<wp:category_parent></wp:category_parent>
<wp:cat_name><![CDATA[{category_name}]]></wp:cat_name>
</wp:category>
{/exp:weblog:categories}
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="default_site" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="200" offset="0" rdf="off"}
<item>
<title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
<link>localhost:8000/?p={entry_id}</link>
<pubDate>{entry_date format="{DATE_RSS}"}</pubDate>
<dc:creator><![CDATA[{author}]]></dc:creator>
{categories}

<category domain="category" nicename="{category_url_title}"><![CDATA[{category_name}]]></category>
{/categories}
<guid isPermaLink="false">localhost:8000/?p={entry_id}</guid>
<description></description>
<content:encoded><![CDATA[{body}]]></content:encoded>
<wp:meta_key>extended</wp:meta_key>
<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{extended}]]></wp:meta_value>
<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[{summary}]]></excerpt:encoded>
<wp:post_id>{entry_id}</wp:post_id>
<wp:post_date>{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date>
<wp:post_date_gmt>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date_gmt>
<wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
<wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
<wp:status>publish</wp:status>
<wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
<wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
<wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
<wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
<wp:postmeta>

</wp:postmeta>
{embed="comments.xml" the_entry_id="{entry_id}"}
</item>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
</channel>
</rss>
```